# Want to Transfer Remove image to Image hosting site

Tags: php, upload, host, transfer

I try to find a solution to transfer image to remove server with php..

For Example i have image http://example.com/image.jpg.. and want to transfer this link/file to http://postimage.org or any other image hosting service.. if you have any solution in PHP Please let me know..

**EDIT:**

After transfer image file its shows me the download link.. Special for http://postimage.org site..

Thanks,

Comment: does the example server not qualify as hosting service?

Comment: actually i don't want to upload at http://imgur.com/ site.. i am running a site which i add multiple poster so i need a solution to only add link of image and automaticly upload to imagehosting site.. (using post/fsockopen or curl method and after upload its shows me the upload link..)

Answer (score 1):

Post image has an upload from url feature:

http://postimage.org/index.php?um=url

Enter the url to your image there and submit.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very open question, but I'll try to answer it.

If you want to upload pictures to a image hosting site, you need to search for one that has an  [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface).

I would recommend [imgur](http://imgur.com/) for starting.

It has free (limited) access to its API by just registering and it is very simple to use.

Read about it [here](http://api.imgur.com/).

It even has an example for [uploading images in PHP](http://api.imgur.com/examples):

```
<?
    $filename = "image.jpg";
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $data = fread($handle, filesize($filename));

    // $data is file data
    $pvars   = array('image' => base64_encode($data), 'key' => IMGUR_API_KEY);
    $timeout = 30;
    $curl    = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://api.imgur.com/2/upload.xml');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pvars);

    $xml = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close ($curl);
?>
```